# Help with macromedia dreamweaver 8

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Hey there!, i have a work to do, a web-aplication for the college, and i already downloaded and installed de apache server 2.2, the php 2.17 (Something like that), but when i come to use de macromedia dreamweaver and select php option, when i wrote php tags they appear in red. I asked for this in my college but in terms of configuration they dont know how to make php work with macromedia dreamweaver 8. Do anyone here can tell me how to do the configuration?, thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Make sure you select a php page NOT HTML. If you select HTML php code coloring will not work.(php 2.17!? we are now in 5.3.5! )

Comment: I know i know xD, is php 5.2.17, i didn't remenber when i asked. I do select php option, but then the colors of php tags goes red, and when i wrote, for example "echo "Hello word";, and i go to see the result in the desing, only appears a gold square with the words php on it :S

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

http://www.pixeldigest.com/phpserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver 8 comes with a library of PHP functions / language elements for highlighting.  If you don't like the color, that's just an option you can change (Edit -> Preferences -> Code Coloring).  There really isn't anything you need to setup to work with php.

Comment: The thing is that when i wrote echo "hello word"; in the code view, when i change it to desing view only appears a golden square with the words php on it, and no matter what i write always that square appears :S